# How to query using the last id of a query using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Explaining further:

This is my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(
    function loadAll (param) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {task: "load", last_id: param},
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, attr) {
                    $("#result").append("<tr><td style='width:300px;'>" + attr.actor_id + "</td><td style='width:300px;'>" + attr.first_name + "</td>");
                })
            }
        })
    });
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
        //Perform the loadAll() function using the last ID of the last query performed
        //and then appending it to the #result
   }
});
```

Here I am basically sending a request and appending it to the `#result` in my html. Then when the user scrolls all the way down, I would like the function to send the `last_id` of the last query performed and retrieve a new query with the new items returned.

This is my PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == "load") {

    $last_id = isset($_POST['last_id'] ) ? (int)$_POST['last_id'] : 0; 

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM actor WHERE actor_id > (?) ORDER BY actor_id LIMIT 0, 30");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $last_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();   

    $encode[] = array(); 

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $encode[] = $row;
    }
        echo json_encode($encode);
}
```

This query checks whether there is a 'last_id' set, and if there isn't, then the last_id is set to 0. This works fine.

This is my HTML (if it matters):

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Making an infinite scroll</h1>
    <p>Load posts below:</p>

    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

The question: **How to query using the last id of a query using AJAX, and then make another query using the last id?**

This is a procedure of what I envision:

**1-** POST Request, returns first query [actors with the actor_id from 0, 30], appends it to #result

**2-** Save the last id of the query into a variable

**3-** If the user scrolls down to the end of the page, perform another query using the last id of the last query [actors with the actor_id of 30, to 60], and then appends it to the #result div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please forgive me if this is a repost or an already-asked question.

Comment: I really want to help, but unfortunately I'm having a hard time understanding. Let's start with: what is NOT happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send last fetched id along with your query results

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $encode[] = $row;
}

$last_id = $encode[count($encode)-1]['actor_id'];

echo json_encode( array('encoded' => $encode, 'last_id' => $last_id) );
```

And then on the client side (your jquery code), you just do smth like this:

```
    var last_id = 0;

    function loadAll (param) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {task: "load", last_id: param},
            success: function(data) {
                results = data.encoded;
                last_id = data.last_id;
                $.each(results, function(i, attr) {
                    $("#result").append("<tr><td style='width:300px;'>" + attr.actor_id + "</td><td style='width:300px;'>" + attr.first_name + "</td>");
                })
            }
        })
    }

$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
         loadAll(last_id);
        //Perform the loadAll() function using the last ID of the last query performed
        //and then appending it to the #result
   }
});
```

I'm not sure if I got the question right, but I guess this is a possible solution of your problem.

PS:

```
SELECT * FROM actor WHERE actor_id > (?) ORDER BY actor_id LIMIT 0, 30
```

Is there any specific reason why you're not doing it like

```
SELECT * FROM actor ORDER BY actor_id LIMIT (?), 30
```

Comment: thank you. That's actually a mistake of mine. I will try the code now.

Comment: It did it! I had to tweak it quite a bit but you led me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question so you may need to expand as it isn't clear.

However you do have a syntax error.

You are stating that 'last_id' is a GET request when it is a POST request.

Should be like so:

```
(isset($_POST['last_id']) && $_POST['last_id'] >= 1) ? $last_id = $_POST['last_id'] : $last_id = 0;
```

Comment: My apologies. I have fixed it.
I will elaborate my question right now.